# Searching a Listview by column for records that either match or contain textbox text, and removing those that don't

Tags: vb.net

This is the coding that I have so far. Allow me to briefly describe what is meant to happen. There is a text box called txtFirst for First Name, a btnSearch and a ListView (lvwDetails). In the ListView there are several columns, and at the moment I'm only searching the first column which is first names. There is also two radio dials, one rdbChecked and the other rdbMatches.

When btnSearch is clicked, it searches the first column (first names) for values that either match or contain the text in the text box depending on which RadioDialButton is checked. If they match then the row is left alone, however if it doesn't match or contain the text, it is removed from the listview.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim MatchFound As Boolean = False
    Dim TempStringFirst As String = ""
    If txtFirst.Text > "" And Not txtFirst.Text = "First Name" Then
        For Each Item As ListViewItem In lvwDetails.Items
            TempStringFirst = Item.Text
            If rdbMatches.Checked = True Then
                If Not InStr(txtFirst.Text, TempStringFirst, CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                    ' delete selected
                End If
            ElseIf rdbContains.Checked = True Then
                If Not TempStringFirst.Contains(txtFirst.Text) Then
                    ' delete selected
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Else
        ' none selected
    End If
End Sub
```

The rdbMathes.Checked = True event works, and the rdbContains event works except it doesn't work with capitals, so if I search for "M" it will show all items that contain a capital M, but won't include a noncapital m in that search. I tested this with message boxes. What is the code to fix this, and also how do I remove the item/row if it doesn't meet requirements?

Many thanks fellas,
Burge.

Comment: Could you use `.ToLower()` to get everything using the same case, then perform your `.Contains()` check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to compare two strings while ignoring capitalization is to convert them both to all upper/lower/proper case and compare the results. For example:

```
TempStringFirst = UCase(Item.Text)
```

and

```
If Not TempStringFirst.Contains(UCase(txtFirst.Text)) Then
```

As for deleting the items, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139147/remove-items-from-listview)

Comment: Works well, thanks mate. Can't believe I missed something so simple!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) or [String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.110).aspx) with [StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) (or OrdinalIgnoreCase if you don't have culture problems) to check strings ignoring case.

You can't delete an item inside a for-each loop, cause it will throw an [InvalidOperationException](http://www.dotnetperls.com/invalidoperationexception), so you can put every items that need to be deleted in a List and delete all of them in another for-each loop.

```
Dim TempStringFirst As String = ""
If txtFirst.Text > "" And Not txtFirst.Text = "First Name" Then
    Dim ItemsToDelete as List(Of ListViewItem) = new List(Of ListViewItem)()
    For Each Item As ListViewItem In lvwDetails.Items
        TempStringFirst = Item.Text
        If rdbMatches.Checked = True Then
            If String.Compare(txtFirst.Text, TempStringFirst,  StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                ItemsToDelete.Add(Item)
            End If
        ElseIf rdbContains.Checked = True Then
            If TempStringFirst.IndexOf(txtFirst.Text,  StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > 0 Then
                ItemsToDelete.Add(Item)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ItemsToDelete
        lvwDetails.Items.Remove(Item)
    Next
Else
    ' none selected
End If
```

Comment: I tried that, however it throws up an error for the rdbCOntains event.
    "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IndexOf' can be called without a narrowing conversion:"
It also throws out an error for ItemsToDelete.Add(Item), it says that 
    "Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode'."

Comment: I've used the other method for the searching function, tweaked it and it works perfectly now, problem is I still can't delete those that don't match. Do you have any idea on how to fix the adding to seperate listview item to delete.

Comment: Sorry, it was a fast copy-paste, see my edited version. Simply change (Of TreeNode) in (Of ListViewItem), and String.IndexOf in TempStringFirst.IndexOf